# From list to unique ID number AND back

Tags: list-manipulation, hashing

If I have a series of list of the form $L_k=\{a_1, a_2,...a_n\}_k$ with $-4<a_i<4$ and $a_i\in\mathbb Z$, then I can make a unique ID number for $L_k$ using `ID_k = FromDigits[L + 4]` and I can go back to $L_k$ using `First[RealDigits[ID]] - 4`.(If I am not mistaken)

For example if:

```
L = {-3, -2, 0, 1, 3}
ID = 12457
```

ID should be unique I think, and I can go from L to ID and from ID to L without ambiguity.

Now how should I adapt this process if $-6<a_i<6$? The problem is that now $L+7$ contains double digits numbers or decimal numbers...

**Question:** Is there an easy  way that displays both unicity and reversibility and that is not time consuming (I have to go back from list to ID many many times)? How would you do it ?

I think hashing is not collision free  (I have about 11 000 000 such lists ) and it is not clear to me how I should go back from the hash code to the list  without storing additional information.

I think I can do it using for example the alphabet, for example:

```
list = {{-2, 2}, {2, 2}, {-4, 4}, {4, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 2}}
id = (StringRiffle[Flatten[FromLetterNumber[list + 7]], ""] // 
    AbsoluteTiming)[[2]]
LetterNumber[StringSplit[id, ""]] - 7 // AbsoluteTiming
```

But string IDs are heavier to store than number IDs and these operations are quite slow (2 ms on my machine). Do you have better?

Answer (score 5):

If you are doing all the lookups within a single kernel session, then you can just store the ID numbers as down values:

```
Module[{lastID = 0, ids, reverse, addEntry},
    addEntry[list_] := With[
        {newID = PreIncrement @ lastID},
        ids[list] = newID;
        reverse[newID] = list;
        newID
    ];
    toId[list_] := Replace[ids @ list, _ids :> addEntry[list]];
    fromId[id_] := Replace[reverse @ id, _reverse :> $Failed];
]
```

The timing is comparable to the `FromDigits` method above:

```
In[2]:= lists = RandomInteger[{-5, 5}, {200000, 8}];
idlist = toId /@ lists; // AbsoluteTiming
roundTripped = fromId /@ idlist; // AbsoluteTiming
lists === roundTripped

Out[3]= {1.38589, Null}

Out[4]= {0.438251, Null}

Out[5]= True
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use a larger base.

```
n = 8;
p = 6-1;
base = 2 p + 1;
L = RandomInteger[{-p, p}, {200000, n}];

ClearAll[toID, fromID];
toID[L_] := FromDigits[L + p, base];
fromID[ID_] := IntegerDigits[ID, base, n] - p;
```

Here a usage example:

```
IDs = toID /@ L; // AbsoluteTiming // First
L2 = fromID /@ IDs; // AbsoluteTiming // First
L2 == L
```

> 0.877335
>
> 1.05924
>
> True

It is not really super fast, though, because we have to use `Map` because `FromDigits` and `IntegerDigits` are vectorized. But it gives an idea.